# SQL Operators as text in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, operators, case

I have the following table, which is used for storing bandings. The table is maintained via a web frontend.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Banding](
[BandingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ValueLowerLimitOperator] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ValueLowerLimit] [decimal](9, 2) NULL,
[ValueUpperLimitOperator] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ValueUpperLimit] [decimal](9, 2) NULL,
[VolumeLowerLimitOperator] [varchar](10) NULL
```

The operator fields store values such as > < >= <=. I want to get to a position where I can use the operators values stored in the table in a case statement in a where clause. Like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CASE ValueLowerLimitOperator
WHEN '<' THEN VALUE < X
WHEN '>' THEN VALUE > X END
```

rather than having to write mutiple case or if statements for each permutation.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can decode the operators values stored in the table as part of my query and then use them in a case/where statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [dynamic sql](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160). Without more information though I can't give you more of an example than in the link

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yeah I could do that, but would prefer to avoid it and work with static SQL.

Answer (score 2):

There are several techniques, but there is something to be aware of; trying to compress two types of functionality into a single query often results in poor execution plans. (Table or Index scans, rather than Index Seeks, for example.)

I've often found it better to rethink the design of the data, and/or rethink how to form the query.

Answering the Specific example in you question, however, I'd do this...

```
WHERE
  CASE WHEN VALUE < X THEN 1
       WHEN VALUE = X THEN 2
       WHEN VALUE > X THEN 4
  END
  |
  CASE ValueLowerLimitOperator
       WHEN '<'       THEN 1
       WHEN '<='      THEN 3
       WHEN '='       THEN 2
       WHEN '>='      THEN 6
       WHEN '>'       THEN 4
  END
  <>
  0
```

This certainly won't be taking advantage of any indexes, however.

Another option is just to code every scenario...

```
WHERE
  CASE ValueLowerLimitOperator
       WHEN '<'       THEN CASE WHEN VALUE <  X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN '<='      THEN CASE WHEN VALUE <= X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN '='       THEN CASE WHEN VALUE =  X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN '>='      THEN CASE WHEN VALUE >= X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN '>'       THEN CASE WHEN VALUE >  X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  END
  =
  1
```

Or possibly a bunch of unioned queries

```
WITH main_query AS (SELECT * FROM blah)
SELECT * FROM main_query WHERE ValueLowerLimitOperator = '<'  AND VALUE <  X
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM main_query WHERE ValueLowerLimitOperator = '<=' AND VALUE <= X
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM main_query WHERE ValueLowerLimitOperator = '='  AND VALUE =  X
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM main_query WHERE ValueLowerLimitOperator = '>=' AND VALUE >= X
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM main_query WHERE ValueLowerLimitOperator = '>'  AND VALUE >  X
```

Maybe even use a function to decode it all?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  main_query
CROSS APPLY
  dbo.my_function(ValueLowerLimitOperator, VALUE, X) AS check
WHERE
  check.return_value = 1

(Using CROSS APPLY with a Inline Table Valued Function will be MUCH faster than a Scalar Function in the WHERE clause)
```

As you look like you want this repeated for LowerLimit, UpperLimit, etc, encapsulating this in a function feels like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the values:

1 for >, -1 for <, 2 for >=, -2 for <=, 0 for =

and then try to check the result of

```
value * ValueLowerLimitOperator  -x*(ValueLowerLimitOperator)
```

you can select like this:

```
select *
from table
where 1=
case 
when (value * ValueLowerLimitOperator  -x*ValueLowerLimitOperator >=0 and abs(ValueLowerLimitOperator)>1)      
    --that means it is <= or >= and the condition is true.
or (value * ValueLowerLimitOperator -x*ValueLowerLimitOperator >0 and abs(ValueLowerLimitOperator)=1)
   --that means it is < or >  and the condition is true.
or (value =x and ValueLowerLimitOperator=0)
   --that means it is = and the condition is true.
then 1
end
```

This will do it.

Comment: I thought of that kind of thing, until I read the question; it needs `<=`, `=` and `>=` as well as `<` and `>`...

Comment: It can be solved. Change the state to -2(<=), 1(>), -1(<), 2 (>=) and do something like value * operator - x*abs(opertaor) and check whether the abs of the operator is bigger than 1 and the result 0 or the other way. But I have to admit it will make my solution much more complicated. Even though, it is still a solution...

Comment: Write the full solution for the OP in your answer then :)  If it does what the OP asked for, I'll upvote ya...

Comment: Thanks Sara, you seem to be onto something here, but could you post your full solution like Dems suggested?